# Why would Freeform give me a full webpage back in the ajax response rather than a json message?

Tags: ajax, forms, solspace-freeform, solspace

I've got a freeform form that is setup to be ajax submitted. However, even though it all works and it sends an e-mail without page refresh, i don't get a json message back, it gives me a full webpage in the response.

My freeform code is like:

```
{exp:freeform:form
collection="Single Product Enquiry"
required=""
notify="me@me.com"
template="single_product_enquiry_form"
ajax="yes"
form:id="ajax_form"
}
```

and ajax code like this:

```
$('#ajax_form').ajaxForm(function(data) {
                if(data.success === true)
                {
                    $("#modal-action").hide();
                    $("#modal-reaction").show();
                }

                if(data.success === false)
                {
                    //$(".form-error-holder").html("<label class='error'>"+data.errors.join(', ')+"</label><input type='text' class='error' /><small class='error'>Invalid entry</small>");

                    $.each(data.errors, function(i, item)
                    {
                        $(".form-error-holder").append("<small class='error'>"+i+": "+item+"</small>");
                    });
                }
            });
```

But i'm just not getting that json response. Any idea why?

Comment: is ajax="yes" required? I thought freeform autodetects that (for graceful degradation on the client). Could it be that you're actually accidentally triggering ajax="no" with that param?

Comment: Well, i do believe that you sir are a legend! If you add that as an answer rather than a comment, i'll accept it and upvote it! Thanks!!

Comment: n.p. answer added - really it's lazy of solspace not to check for `ajax="no"` rather than just the presence of an `ajax` param but I suspect it's for speed of parsing.

Comment: Sure, it also transpires that i was a whole version behind. So, perhaps that is not the case in the latest version. I'm very grateful for the help, cheers!

Comment: Yep. that'll do it to :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that ajax="yes" is required?

I believe freeform autodetects that (for graceful degradation on the client).

I haven't checked the FreeForm source but I suspect it could be that you're actually accidentally triggering ajax="no" with that param.